# Event on start play remote mp3 in MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player

I set in MediaPlayer source as url with remote mp3 file. I want listen, where start playing song.

At start some time need to download mp3 header (caching) and only after start playing song. How I can know about this moment? I know only simple way: check at timer isPlaying status...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Android native MediaPlayer, there's an event called onPrepare which is called when the mediaplayer is ready to play your music

For example how to catch the above event on VideoView.

```
video = new VideoView(activity);
video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

}
```

Comment: Probably you mistake. But anyway I still haved issue: player start working, after I seek progress to the end song (for example: 90%). Ofcouse, this song part do not downloaded and some time player will be at pause. After loading data, player continue work.

Comment: I guess you want to capture every time the media player buffering for content? In this case onPrepared event should only help when you first start playing the song. I would suggest a hack that you have a handler running every sec and check for the currentPosition. If the position does not increase, that means the media player is buffering.